# REGEX Date Match Format

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

I currently have a dataset with varying date entries (and a mixture of string entries) for which I need to parse. There are a few: `'M/DD/YY'`, `'M/D/YY'`, `'MM/DD/YY'`, `'MM/D/YY'`, `'MM/DD/YYYY'`...). I could use some support with improving my regex to handle the varying formats and possible text entered in the date field.

My current Postgres query breaks out other entries into another column and reformats the date. Although, I've increased the year to 4 digits rather than 2, I believe the issue may live somewhere in the `'YYYY-MM-DD'` formatting or that my query does not properly accommodate additional formatting within.

```
CASE WHEN date ~ '^\\\\d{1,2}/\\\\d{1,2}/\\\\d{4}$' THEN TO_DATE(date::date, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
     ELSE NULL END AS x_date,

CASE WHEN NOT date ~ '^\\\\d{1,2}/\\\\d{1,2}/\\\\d{4}$' AND date <> '' THEN date
     ELSE NULL END AS x_date_text
```

For the various date formats, they should be reformatted accordingly and for other non-date values, they should be moved over to the other column.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your list of formats, I believe that just two regexes should be enough to check the values:

- `'^[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{4}/$'` would map to date format `'MM/DD/YYYY'`
- `'^[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{2}/$'` would map to `'MM/DD/YY'`

You can use a `CASE` construct to check the value against the regex and apply the proper mask when using `TO_DATE()`.

However, since you need to split the data over two columns, you would need to tediously repeat the `CASE` expression twice, one for each column.

One way to simplify the solution (and to make it easier to maintain afterwards) would be to use a CTE to list the regexes and the associated date format. You can `LEFT JOIN` the CTE with the table.

Consider the following query:

```
WITH vars AS (
    SELECT '^[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{4}/$' reg, 'MM/DD/YYYY' format
    UNION ALL '^[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{2}/$', 'MM/DD/YY'
)
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN vars.reg IS NOT NULL THEN TO_DATE(t.date, vars.format) END x_date,
    CASE WHEN vars.reg IS NULL THEN t.date  END x_date_text
FROM 
    mytable t
    LEFT JOIN vars ON t.date ~ vars.reg
```

If more regex/format pairs are needed, you just have to expand the CTE. Just pay attention to the fact that regexes should be exclusives (ie two different regexes should not possibly match on a single value), else you will get duplicated records in the result.

Comment: Thanks, GMB. Why you're suggesting the above result is incredibly helpful. I'll just need to better expand the syntax to include additional date fields. One note in simply testing the above, I'm receiving an AWS syntax error "at or near" the following: `'^[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{2}/$'` (position 102). Am I forgetting something when incorporating the above format?

Answer (score 0):

While the regex by @GMB insures format validity it passes many invalid dates, and with liberal to_date conversion by Postgres could introduce errors and or confusion. Run the following to see the liberal conversion:

```
set datestyle = 'ISO';
select dd,'01/' || dd || '/2019' mmddyyyy, to_date ( '01/' || dd || '/2019', 'mm/dd/yyyy') 
   from ( select generate_series( 0,40)::text  dd) d;

 select mm , mm ||'/01/2019' mmddyyyy, to_date ( mm ||'01/2019', 'mm/dd/yyyy') 
   from ( select generate_series( 0,40)::text  mm) d;
```

If that liberal date conversion is acceptable - Great. But if not we can tighten it down considerable (although still not 100% valid results). Lets break the format down:

```
for date formats mm/dd/yyyy or mm/dd/yy
breakdown MM  valid 1 - 12   
              valid character  0 followed by 1-9  
                               1 followed by 0-2
              regex  (0?[1-9]|1[0-2)

          DD valid 0 - 31 (sort of) 
             day 31 valid for April, June, Sep, Nov also evaluate valid but become 
             day 1 of May, July, Oct, Dec respectivally 

             days 29-31 of Feb also eveluate valid but become day 
             1-3 of march and 1-2 in lead yearsin non-leap years 

             valid character optional 0 followed by 1-9
                                      1-2 followed by 0-9
                                      3 followed by 0-1
             regex (0?[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-2])


         YEAR valid 1900 - 2999 (no ancient history)
           valid character  1-2 followed by 0-9,0-9,0-9
                            0-9,0-9
```

Now putting that together we get.

```
    -- setup   
    drop table if exists my_dates;       
    create table my_dates(test_date text, status text);
    insert into my_dates (test_date, status) 
         values ('01/15/2019', 'valid')
              , ('12/25/0001', 'invalid year < 1900')
              , ('12/01/2020', 'valid')
              , ('oops',       'yea a date NOT')
              , ('6/3/19',     'valid')
              , ('2/29/2019',  'valid sort of,  Postgres liberal evaluation of to_date')
              , ('2/30/2019',  'valid sort of,  Postgres liberal evaluation of to_date')
              , ('2/31/2019',  'valid sort of,  Postgres liberal evaluation of to_date')                    
              , ('2/29/2020',  'valid')
              , ('14/29/2020', 'invalid month 14')
              , ('01/32/2019', 'invalid day 32')
              , ('04/31/2019', 'valid sort of,  Postgres liberal evaluation of to_date')
              ;

-- as query
set datestyle = 'ISO';              
with patterns (pat, fmt) as (values ('^(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])/(0?[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])/[12][0-9]{3}$'::text, 'mm/dd/yyyy')
                                  , ('^(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])/(0?[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])/[0-9]{2}$'::text,     'mm/dd/yy')
                            )
select to_date(test_date, fmt),status, test_date, pat, fmt
  from my_dates
   left join patterns on  test_date ~ pat;                                            

 ------------------------------------------------------------------ 
 -- function accessable from SQL
 create or replace function parse_date(check_date_in text)
 returns date 
 language sql
 as $$ 
     with patterns (pat, fmt) as (values ('^(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])/(0?[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])/[12][0-9]{3}$'::text, 'mm/dd/yyyy')
                                       , ('^(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])/(0?[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])/[0-9]{2}$'::text,     'mm/dd/yy')
                                 )
     select to_date(check_date_in, fmt)
       from patterns
      where check_date_in ~ pat;   
 $$;                

--- test function 
select test_date, parse_date(test_date), status from my_dates; 

-- use demo
select * from my_dates 
 where parse_date(test_date) >= date '2020-01-02';
```